# TypeError: ("unhashable type: 'slice'", 'occurred at index 0') Pandas DataFrame .apply problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

So I've been working on some American football data. The team is the Gators. The data didn't have a column for weather or not they won or lost so I've been trying to add a new column.

I defined a function that is suppose to read the data from certain columns to indicate if they won...

```
def wins(gators_past):
if gators_past.loc(axis=0)[:,1] == 'Florida' and gators_past.loc[:,17] > gators_past.loc[:,34]:
    val='Gators Win'
elif gators_past.loc[:,1] == 'Florida' and gators_past.loc[:,17] < gators_past.loc[:,34]:
    val='Gators Lose'
elif gators_past.loc[:,18] == 'Florida' and gators_past.loc[:,17] > gators_past.loc[:,34]:
    val='Gators Lose'
elif gators_past.loc[:,18] == 'Florida' and gators_past.loc[:, 17] < gators_past.loc[:, 34]:
    val='Gators Win'
return val
```

And then I created the new column in the dataframe...

```
gators_past['Gators Win/Lose'] = gators_past.apply(wins, axis=1)

print(gators_past['Gators Win/Lose'])
```

However I just get

```
TypeError: ("unhashable type: 'slice'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

I've researched it and many were saying its a problem with .loc/.iloc use. I've checked all the places I've used it and everything seems to be in order. Any ideas of what is going wrong? Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Does the error stack trace give you a line number to help narrow down the location of the issue?

Comment: It’s calling it to the line I create the column, but everything there seems right to me.